# Prepared Statement on Ubuntu shows ERROR, not in Windows

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, prepared-statement

Ok, i got this code which works fine in Windows but not in Ubuntu 11.04.
I got PHP 5.3.5 on both of those OS and same MySQL version.

My code

```
$dba_host='localhost';
$dba_name='root';
$dba_pass='';
$dba_db='sn';
$con=mysqli_connect($dba_host,$dba_name,$dba_pass,$dba_db) or die('Connection Refused !');

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT UID,Name,Trace from LOGIN where email=? and password=? LIMIT 1"); // Line 50
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $_POST['login'],$_POST['password']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $uid, $name, $trace);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

**Error**

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given on line 50
Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given  on line 51
Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given line 52\
Warning: mysqli_stmt_fetch() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given  on line 53
Warning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given on line 54
```

**Additional INfo**
I am the root user, and i can see the tables through phpMyAdmin

Comment: If you're saying the code gives an error on Ubuntu, you might want to tell us *which* error you're getting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error; PHP/MySQL in Ubuntu is not smart enough to find the table if the identifier's case does not match. So table `LOGIN` and `login` are completely different.

Comment: yup, in windows 'SQL' table and 'sql' table is same, but not in Ubuntu.

Comment: See this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: You can set `lower_case_table_names=1` as one option. You could also try using all table and database names in lower case (everywhere), so you accustom yourself with Unix habits :)

Comment: yup, i did the 2nd thing, btw how to do the first thing ?

Comment: You should look into how (MySQL) system variables can be changed (tempoarirly) or permanently: Check the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-system-variables.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ubuntu not being "smart enough". It's a specific, explicit, design feature that identifiers in Linux tend to be case-sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given on line 50

In that case, apparently, mysqli_prepare doesn't return a *mysqli stmt* resource, but a boolean (most probably "false"). You can request the latest error mysqli has returned as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT UID,Name,Trace from LOGIN where email=? and password=? LIMIT 1";
if( !mysqli_prepare( $con, $query ) ) {
    echo mysqli_error( $con );
}
```

That will display what actually went wrong. Learn defensive programming: don't assume a function will always work, as bad things will happen sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

**As per my understanding it is problem of connection i can see there is blank password...i have also running with ubuntu.In ubuntu you have to give the password @ configuration time for mysql root account so Please cross check with that.
I am pretty sure that you have connection problem. Please check it if anything else give me comments i will resolve it**

Please also check with your table LOGIN with same name in database.

```
Usually database name or Table name is Case Senstive.
```

Comment: nopes, i'm running XAMPP not LAMPP, and PMA also dont have passwords. If it was a problem of connection it should have shown **Connection Refused !**